# Mongodb Compass: How to tie object import to user?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-compass

My database has 2 collections: Notes and Users. I can import a Note as a json file and see it in the database. However, the Users collection doesn't update even though the json file contains the User (creator) id. How can I update the User with the new Note id without having to do it manually?

**When I import a Note to the Notes collection,**

```
{
  "title": "title",
  "description": "description",
  "creator": {
    "$oid": "64ecfacb5b435db86dff6c16"
  },
}
```

**I want to auto update the Notes array in the User collection:**

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "64ecfacb5b435db86dff6c16"
  },
  "name": "username",
  "email": "username@username.com",
  "password": "$2a$12$KAm/qGL1E0ivjWnpJSje/.vFRZ9a4cfXv8t0thMrs8PIH.JNh9MNO",
  
  "notes": [
    {
      "$oid": "64fdb7fcb5eb57e21dcecfa3"
    },
    {
      "$oid": "651868f4c644d12c8df13ea5"
    },
    ** auto populate new note here **
  ],
  "__v": 370
}
```

Comment: Using just the Compass client? You'd have to script something in the embedded shell or, if using Atlas, have a trigger set. No other automatic way as far as I know

Comment: Agree with @user20042973. If doing this via Compass or mongosh then you would need [Database Triggers](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/atlas/app-services/triggers/database-triggers/). For Atlas there are code examples that you can leverage for your own use case [here](https://github.com/mongodb/atlas-app-services-examples/tree/main/triggers-examples) .